# ¿Cómo puedo retornar el valor de una promesa dentro de una función?

Tags: javascript, promesas

Deseo retornar el valor obtenido en una promesa dentro de una función.
Es decir, deseo asignar el valor de una variable mediante una función que ejecuta una promesa pero no logro solucionar el problema.

```js
const log = console.log.bind(console);

function _rPromise() {
  // Variable que deseo retornar
  // por fuera de la función
  let $r = null; 
  let _promise = new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve("¡Éxito!");
      }, 250);
    }
  );

  _promise.then(
    function(result) {
      return $r;
    }
  );
}

const _vPromise = _rPromise();
log(_vPromise);
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que debes hacer es devolver la promesa en la función `_rPromise()`.

Luego puedes hacer uso de las [**`funciones asíncronas`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona) y utilizar [**`await`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) para obtener el valor de la promesa.

```js
function _rPromise() {
  // Variable que deseo retornar
  // por fuera de la función
  let $r = null; 
  let _promise = new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve("¡Éxito!");
      }, 250);
    }
  );

  // No hace falta
  /*_promise.then(
    function(result) {
      return $r;
    }
  );*/
  
  return _promise; // Devolver la promesa
}

(async function (){
  // Con await estás bloqueando la ejecución de la función
  // hasta que _rPromise() o más bien la promesa que devuelve sea resuelta
  // Puedes hacer uso de un bloque try/catch en caso
  // de que la promesa sea rechazada
  // let res = await _rPromise();
  // console.log(res);
  console.log( await _rPromise() );
})()
```

La palabra reservada await solo puede ser usada dentro de una función asíncrona.

Otra característica de las `async functions` es que devuelven una promesa:

```
(async function(){...})().then(...)
```

Podemos hacer uso de un bloque try/catch en lugar de utilizar el método catch de la promesa:

```js
Promise.reject('Error').catch(function(e){
  console.log(e);
});

// Podemos hacer esto

(async function (){
  try{
    await Promise.reject('Error 2');
  } catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
})();
```

Comment: ¿es necesaria la función autoinvocada para poder obtener el valor?

Comment: Se me olvidó comentarlo. Buena apreciación. En sí no es necesaria la IIFE, pero sí una función asíncrona : `async function f(){...}; f();` ya que la palabra reservada await solo puede ser usada dentro de una función asíncronas. Otra característica de las `async functions` es que devuelven una promesa. `(async function(){...})().then(...)` Te recomiendo que visites el link para saber más sobre las funciones asíncronas. Saludos =)

Comment: ¿Puedes editar tu respuesta para que agregues el comentario anterior y un breve ejemplo del try catch para aceptar tu respuesta?

Comment: Claro, ¡allá voy!, dame unos minutos =)

Comment: En total se necesitarían de dos funciones para poder obtener el valor de una promesa, es lo que entiendo

Comment: Sí, ten en cuenta que este patrón `async/await` no dejar de ser azúcar sintáctico para obtener el valor de una promesa.`await promise;console.log('')` es básicamente lo mismo que `promise.then(function(){console.log('')})`. Solo que await solo puede ser usado dentro de una función asíncrona.

Comment: En este GIST puedes ver que las funciones asíncronas son azúcar sintáctico encima de Promises y Generators: https://gist.github.com/ChrisChares/1ed079b9a6c9877ba4b43424139b166d

Comment: Aunque fuiste muy claro, sigo sin obtener lo que deseo :(

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65098/discussion-between-jose-hermosilla-rodrigo-and-jorius).

Comment: Hola Jorius me parece que la respuesta que te dio @Jose es buena, a mi si me funcionó para obtener el valor fuera del promise, no te lo tomes a mal pero por lo menos debería tener punto a favor, ya que gastó su tiempo y esfuerzo en ayudarte y dar una buena respuesta.